# Getting battery level using services

Tags: android

Here I need to get the status of Battery with services.Service get the state of the battery after every second and when I disconnect the device it shows How much time USB attached to the Device?Please suggest the solution...............

```
 public class serviceclass extends Service{

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
     @Override
       public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
          // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
          Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          return START_STICKY;
       }
       @Override
       public void onDestroy() {
          super.onDestroy();
          Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
}
```

Comment: Yes the code you pasted above is just a simple service example code. Let us know what have you tried further.

Comment: when I add usb to device it starts service that note down the current time when the usb is attached and it tracks the time after every second and when i remove the usb it will show the time that for how much it was connected.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a service for that.
There are two broadcast receivers to know if external power has been connected and if external power has been removed from the device. If you want to know the time that the device had been connected I would do this:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

private long timeConnected;
private long startConnected;
private long endConnected;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)){
        startConnected = new Calendar().getTimeInMillis();
    } else if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)){
        endConnected = new Calendar().getTimeInMillis();
        timeConnected = endConnected - startConnected;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will show answer in ms or seconds.I want to get time in seconds

Comment: Get the answer in seconds is simple. Now the time is in milliseconds, in seconds will be: timeMilliseconds / 1000